# gremlin error raised while using Neo4Django in my project

Tags: django, neo4j

I have used neo4Django to build the database models in my Django project while running the server it asks gremlin plugin required on my web page

Answer (score 1):

Here this should fixed your problem with gremlin

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin#building-from-source-and-deploying-into-neo4j-server